# How can I clear the cache after updating the Server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, caching

I have developed an app, but when I push the latest version from the app to the Server, the CSS and JS files are not updated. The old files are showing. How can I clear the cache after updating the files?

**EDITED like jcubic**

Now I use the buster in this way.

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AIS</title>
    <script src="index.php"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= with_hash('style.css') ?>">
</head>
```

index.php:

```
<php?

function with_hash($url) {
   return $url . "?" . md5(file_get_contents($url));
}
?>
```

Error message:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/%3C?=%20with_hash(%27style.css%27)%20?%3E' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: PHP code will not work in html files. Please change the extension to php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called cache buster. Add a unique ID to the URL of the JS and CSS in your application. I personally use the hash of the content of the file, you can get it you write the HTML file in PHP or any other server-side script, but PHP, if you have a single HTML file, is the easiest.

In PHP it can look like this:

```php
<php?

function with_hash($url) {
   return $url . "?" . md5(file_get_contents($url));
}
?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= with_hash('produktion.css') ?>">
```

If the application is for static hosting like Netlify you will need to generate an HTML file with the hash. You can easily do that with Webpack.

Comment: I think there are more then 8 html files. Should I use still the cache buster ?

Comment: and how it must look like in my produktion.css file. Should I also add code or only in the html files ?

Comment: @KlausM. Why having more HTML files should change anything? To disable cache you use cache buster there is no other way. Unless you use a service worker, where you can have your own logic to cache files.

Comment: okay I have understand it, but must I add a code snipped also in the js,css files or only in the header from the html files ?

Comment: @KlausM. the solution is simple you have a URL to the resource add something to the end of the file to disable the cache. It doesn't matter where the files are added in the footer and the header or added dynamically. And you don't need to use hash this is just an example you can name your files with a version that is another way to disable unwanted caching.

Comment: now I have edit my post, is it correctly in this way ?

Comment: @KlausM. yes but you need to keep track of the version to update it on each change, with the hash you don't need to change the version manually. Also if you think that the hash is too long you can use sha1 hash and take the first few characters.

Comment: but when I have tried like you I became the following error (See at edited question)

Comment: @KlausM. You can't write PHP code into an HTML file it will not work. Please change the extension to PHP so it's a PHP script.